# Join together two list objects in C#

Tags: c#, list

Basically, I'm coding a poker app and I have a class called `Deck` which is really just a `List<>` contain objects of the class `Card`. It's literally just a list of cards.

I'm now trying to concatenate two of these `Decks` together: `playerCards` and `tableCards`. However, when I write this code, I get an error message:

```
playerCards.Concat(tableCards);
```

It tells me that "'Deck' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'Deck' could be found."

How can I concatenate these two list objects together?

Hopefully this explains Deck a bit better...

```
public class Deck
{

    public Deck()
    {
        deck = new List<Card>();
    }

    public List<Card> deck { get; }
```

Comment: `AddRange` seems appropriate :)

Comment: Yeap, use `list1.AddRange(list2)`;

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Hmm, it's showing the same error only with 'AddRange' instead of 'Concat'...

Comment: post your code.

Comment: The errormessage tells you that the class 'Deck' doesn't have a Concat-method. Include some more code in your question - that increases the chances of getting an answer that helps you.

Comment: Also don't forget to import `System.Linq` for `Concat`.

Comment: @DanielBrixen Alright, do you want the whole Deck class though? I'm not really experienced enough to know which part of the code is the helpful bit.

Comment: Just enough to make 'a class called Deck which is really just a List<>' more concrete.

Comment: @Zetland ah, the `Deck` class. And here we thought, that `deck=new List<Card>();`
You need to create AddRange method for your deck class that will call `AddRange` on the underlying lists.

Comment: Also please _always_ add some code to the questions on SO =)

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Ah, sorry, just added some of the Deck class for you to see, although I'm not sure it's so helpful. Do you have a link for the AddRange code btw? I've tried to find it so I can adapt it for Deck but I don't seem to be looking in the right places...

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov Thank you very much sir. Feel free to add that as an answer if you want and I'll vote it up.

Comment: @Zetland The only answer that should be marked as an answer should be the one from Daniel

Comment: @Icepickle Why?

Comment: @Zetland For one, because he took the time to give you an answer in great detail, while also answering your question. Sergey's answer is well, not very detailed, and though it also answers the question, it is given with lots less attention to detail, it is almost a code only answer, which was previously posted in the comments. However, you are ofcourse free to choose yourself ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Concat method is an extension-method defined in `Enumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<TSource> Concat<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> first, IEnumerable<TSource> second);
```

This means you can use it like this:

```
IEnumerable<Card> deck1 = new List<Card>();
IEnumerable<Card> deck2 = new List<Card>();
IEnumerable<Card> deck3 = deck1.Concat(deck2);
```

It will return a new sequence of Card-objects.

The method `AddRange` is defined for fx `List<T>`:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

Use it like this:

```
List<Card> deck1 = new List<Card>();
List<Card> deck2 = new List<Card>();
deck2.AddRange(deck1);
```

This will modify the list deck1 by adding elements from deck2.

So your choice of how to implement `Concat` or `AddRange` in your class `Deck` depends on which behaviour you want it to have:

- Return a new `Deck` containing cards from both `Deck`s
- Modify the `Deck` by adding cards from the other `Deck`

Perhaps you can use the following as inspiration:

```
public class Deck
{
    private List<Card> cards;

    public IReadOnlyList<Card> Cards
    {
        get
        {
            return cards.AsReadOnly();
        }
    }

    public Deck()
    {
        cards = new List<Card>();
    }

    public Deck(IEnumerable<Card> cards)
    {
        cards = cards.ToList();
    }

    public Deck Concat(Deck other)
    {
        return new Deck(Cards.Concat(other.Cards));
    }

    public void AddRange(Deck other)
    {
        cards.AddRange(other.Cards);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Concat(Deck other)
{
   this.deck.AddRange(other.deck);
}
```

Like this. [List.AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)